# Area of region bounded by $y^2=4x$ and $y=2x-4$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have to plot, put color and calculate the area of $y^2=4x$ and $y=2x-4$ with Mathematica. By hand, I found that the area is the integral of $\frac{y}{2}+2-\frac{y^2}{4}$ in the interval $[-2,4]$. I can use Integrate command and Plot command, but my question is if it is a different way to use Mathematica. I am a beginner. May we use RegionPlot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, George! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 9):

The enclosed region is

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   -2 Sqrt[x] < y < 2 Sqrt[x] && y > 2 x - 4, {x, y}];
```

The area is

```
Area[rgn]

(* 9 *)
```

or

```
RegionMeasure[rgn]

(* 9 *)
```

Which agree with your integral

```
Integrate[y/2 + 2 - y^2/4, {y, -2, 4}]

(* 9 *)

pts = Solve[{y^2 == 4 x, y == 2 x - 4}, {x, y}]

{{x -> 1, y -> -2}, {x -> 4, y -> 4}}

Show[
 ContourPlot[
  {y^2 == 4 x, y == 2 x - 4}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, -3, 5},
  ContourStyle -> Thick, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{x, y} /. pts]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.75, .25}]],
 RegionPlot[
  -2 Sqrt[x] < y < 2 Sqrt[x] && y > 2 x - 4,
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25, LightBlue],
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 Plot[{2 Sqrt[x], -2 Sqrt[x], 2 x - 4},
  {x, -1, 5},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {-3, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{x, y} /. pts]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.75, .25}]],
 RegionPlot[
  -2 Sqrt[x] < y < 2 Sqrt[x] && y > 2 x - 4,
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25, LightBlue],
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Sure! There's a few different ways you could handle it in MMA, but using regions is one way.

First we can define a region:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[y^2 - 4 x <= 0 && 2 x - y <= 4, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[r]
```

[image: Region plot of 2 equations.]

This looks correct to me. Since we've created a region, we can also do something quite neat:

```
Area[r]
```

outputs 9. This is the exact same value you get by evaluating

```
Integrate[y/2 + 2 - y^2/4, {y, -2, 4}]
```